# Angular 6 web app log out user when app launch with bad internet

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

Sometimes when my app launch with a bad internet connection the user got logged out.

I don't want this to happen.. I want the user to continue being logged in even if the app didn't launch properly because of bad internet connection..

```
"@angular/fire": "^5.1.0",
```

I attached my AuthService code, also my dependencies.. what I am doing wrong?

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  public userDetails: firebase.User = null;
  userAuthDoneSubject = new Subject();

  constructor(
    private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.user = firebaseAuth.authState;

    this.user.subscribe(
      (userDetails) => {
        if (userDetails) {
          this.userDetails = userDetails;
        }
        else {
          this.userDetails = null;
        }
        this.userAuthDoneSubject.next();
      },(error) => {this.userAuthDoneSubject.error("AuthService:error authenticate"); }
    );
  }
  isLoggedIn() {
    if (this.userDetails == null ) {
      return false;
    } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
 
    logout() {
       return this.firebaseAuth.auth.signOut();
    }

  signinUser(customToken:any){
    return this.firebaseAuth.auth.signInWithCustomToken(customToken)
  }

  getJWT() {
    return this.firebaseAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true);
  }

}
```

```
"dependencies": {
  "@agm/core": "^1.0.0",
  "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
  "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
  "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
  "@angular/fire": "^5.1.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
  "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
  "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
  "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.19",
  "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^4.6.2",
  "core-js": "^2.5.4",
  "css-toggle-switch": "^4.1.0",
  "firebase": "^5.5.9",
  "ng-lazyload-image": "^6.1.0",
  "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^0.1.2",
  "ngx-page-scroll-core": "^6.0.2",
  "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
  "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
  "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use firebase into a client app, the firebase script will be loaded and then it will check if a previous session exists and then will validate it against auth server. If for some reason internet connection fails, this process will not succeed, so the event onAuthStateChanged will not be fired, which will cause you app state to be in a not logged in state.

Your code is based on a third party library (which I don't know its internals) that wraps firebase functionalities and probably will listen to firebase events.

I suggest you save the firebase token in localStorage when the user logs in, and in case internet connection fails, you can try to log in using the token that was saved in localStorage. Or you can listen to net connection events. Please check this [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/retrying-requests-when-back-online)

Comment: I use AngularFire library, it saves automatically the token in the IndexedDB Storage and make all the work of keeping the user logged in in the background..

Comment: mostly the problem happens when a user start the application and the application fail to load because of bad internet.. then when the user start the application again after fixing the internet.. the user will be logged out.. so if it fails only once it will stay logged out! why is that? as you suggest " you can try to log in using the token that was saved in localStorage" why the app fail to log in after the internet fixed?

Comment: try realoding the firebase auth curentuser instance after internet connection is restored, there is a method firebase.auth().currentUser.reload() which is async

Comment: did you have solved the problem ?

Comment: no :(
,are you facing the same problem?